# Unknown column 'ValidationRequired' in 'field list' MySQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have .Net Core  project with code-first approach.

Here is my migrations where I populate table with enums

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            $"INSERT INTO ValidationStatuses(Id,Name) VALUES({(int) ValidationStatusEnum.ValidationRequired},{ValidationStatusEnum.ValidationRequired})");
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            $"INSERT INTO ValidationStatuses(Id,Name) VALUES({(int) ValidationStatusEnum.Validated},{ValidationStatusEnum.Validated})");
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            $"INSERT INTO TenantTypes(Id,Name) VALUES({(int) TenantTypeEnum.Agency},{TenantTypeEnum.Agency}");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            "DELETE FROM ValidationStatuses");
        migrationBuilder.Sql(
            "DELETE FROM TenantTypes ");
    }
```

When I try to run it I have this

> Unknown column 'ValidationRequired' in 'field list'

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the quotes to tell MySQL it's a String value and not a cloumn.

```
$"INSERT INTO ValidationStatuses(Id,Name) VALUES('{(int) ValidationStatusEnum.ValidationRequired}','{ValidationStatusEnum.ValidationRequired})'");
```

You might need to replace the single quotes I added by double quotes in MySQL.